# Static relocations in linked ELF file, not needed entries in .dynsym table

Tags: linker, arm, ld, elf

My final ELF file contains >500 dynamic relocations of type R_ARM_RELATIVE and 5 static relocations of type R_ARM_ABS32.
As far as I know the static relocations are only needed for static linking. My file is going to be only dynamically linked when loaded.
I've found this information here:
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0044e/IHI0044E_aaelf.pdf

```
Static relocations are processed by a static linker; they are normally either
fully resolved or used to produce dynamic relocations for processing by a
post-linking step or a dynamic loader. A well formed image will have no static
relocations after static linking is complete, so a post-linker or dynamic loader
will normally only have to deal with dynamic relocations.
```

**Why can my file contain static relocations while it is fully linked?**

My other question is about R_ARM_RELATIVE relocations.
They do not use the .dynsym table for relocation process (R_ARM_ABS32 does).
**So why there are so many (>70) symbols in .dynsym table, instead of 5?
Are these symbols used for something else besides the relocation process in dynamic linking?**

Comment: No one can really comment.  How have you produced the ELF?  There will be different forms depending on the compiler and options.  Sometimes the ARM Elf does some dumb things because of [history and the PC](http://netwinder.osuosl.org/users/s/scottb/public_html/notes/Elf-Design-1.html).  I think the compiler/linker will leave a bunch of PC relative `R_ARM_RELATIVE` notations that don't need any fixing at all.  If you want to punch holes in the code by relocating/splitting a section, then you would use these entries.  Like `.rodata` will not follow `.text`, etc.  Give sample assembler and record

Comment: Also, try to use `strip` to make sure things aren't present just for debugging.